# Body not used in response from Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, express

I am sending a url and a param (term which is user generated) to Node JS where i am making a request. I get back the correct data in my Node/Express API but when I send it to the client it says bodyUsed false and the data is not there.
I am using the Deezer API to get back track info.

Here is the React code:

```
const term = this.state.searchTerm; //default set for dev

    fetch(`http://localhost:9000/musicsearch/${term}`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("DATA=> ", response);
        this.setState({
          tracksN: response
        });
      });
```

and the Route on the server side:

```
app.get('/musicsearch/:query', (req, res) => {
    fetch(`https://deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=${req.params.query}`, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "x-rapidapi-host": process.env.RAPID_API_HOST,
            "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.RAPID_API_KEY
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp.data);
            res.json(resp.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send(err);
        });
});
```

The console log in the 2nd .then()block returns the json and logs it in the terminal but the following line returns

```
response {
   body: (...)
   bodyUsed: false
   headers: Headers {}
   ok: true
   redirected: false
   status: 200
   statusText: "OK"
   type: "cors"
   url: "http://localhost:9000/musicsearch/trivium"
   __proto__: Response
}
```

I've used Node for a while now but never came across this particular issue. I must be missing something. Any help is really appreciated.

One more thing. I originally made this call directly from the client and it works perfectly.

```
    fetch("https://deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=" + term, {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_HOST,
        "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY
      }
    })
      .then(data => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          tracks: data,
          currentTrack: null,
          playerStatus: "paused"
        });
        this.audio.src = null;
        //console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: not clear that u interpret bodyUse value of false ... from the spec (spec-compliant)

Boolean
A boolean property for if this body has been consumed. Per the specs, a consumed body cannot be used again. so after you consume the body, bodyUsed value -> true

Comment: But how can I consume it's not in the response. It usually is inside a data attribute.

Comment: after return data.json() in the next ".then"   just send it to the client and verify that you have it there in devtools "net" tab.   ".then(data2 => {res.send(data2)})" where res is from the toplevel  "get (req, res) " in the route.  Then you will know u have good data. go back to server route , do the upd on state there and then send a good response back to client